# Selecting 1st element of every list within list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have the following list of lists with multiple elements:

```
list = [[1633425661439, 0.11643042583898743],
        [1633428739018, 0.11682454707026001],
        [1633432086311, 0.11950356856187618]]
```

I want to populate a `new_list1` and `new_list2` with the first and second numbers within each of those lists, respectively, yielding:

```
new_list1 = [1633425661439,
            1633428739018,
            1633432086311]
```

And:

```
new_list2 = [0.11643042583898743,
            0.11682454707026001,
            0.11950356856187618]
```

I tried:

```
for n in list:
        for i in n:
            new_list1.append(i[0])
            new_list2.append(i[1])
```

But got: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something

```
list_ = [[1633425661439, 0.11643042583898743],
        [1633428739018, 0.11682454707026001],
        [1633432086311, 0.11950356856187618]]

list_a = [first[0] for first in list_]
list_b = [first[1] for first in list_]
```

Other way

```
new_list1 = []
new_list2 = []

for inner_list in list_:
    new_list1.append(inner_list[0])
    new_list2.append(inner_list[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transpose it like this:

```
lst = [[1633425661439, 0.11643042583898743],
       [1633428739018, 0.11682454707026001],
       [1633432086311, 0.11950356856187618]]

new_list_1, new_list_2 = map(list, zip(*lst))
```

And if you are ok with tuples instead of lists, the following will do:

```
new_list_1, new_list_2 = zip(*lst)
```

And you really should not name a variable `list`. It shadows the built-in type.

You can also use simple comprehensions:

```
new_list_1 = [a for a, _ in lst]
new_list_2 = [a for _, a in lst]
```

Some docs:

- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: map is much heavier to use here

Answer (score 1):

You have one level of nesting too much, this would

```
for n in list:
    for i in n:
        print(i)
```

would print single elements, which are numbers, you need to do

```
for n in list:
    new_list1.append(n[0])
    new_list2.append(n[1])
```

As side note, please avoid using `list` as it is already used name in `python`. Overshadowing it might cause unexpected behavior, you can use `lst` name i.e.:

```
lst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
new_lst1 = []
new_lst2 = []
for n in lst:
    new_lst1.append(n[0])
    new_lst2.append(n[1])
print(new_lst1)
print(new_lst2)
```

output

```
[1, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can unpack the first and second number in the for loop itself.
(BTW best not call the variable "list" because it is the same as a python build-in)

```py
list_ = [[1633425661439, 0.11643042583898743],
        [1633428739018, 0.11682454707026001],
        [1633432086311, 0.11950356856187618]]
new_list1 = []
new_list2 = []
for (i, j) in l:
    new_list1.append(i)
    new_list2.append(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Following [PEP-8 code style guideline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) please do not name the variables with reserved keywords like `list`, `dict`, `for`, etc.
2. With the second loop you iterate over `int` numbers within the inner lists.
   If you need to use only the first 2 elements of each list, one loop os enough:

```py
list_ = [
    [1633425661439, 0.11643042583898743],
    [1633428739018, 0.11682454707026001],
    [1633432086311, 0.11950356856187618]]

for inner_list in list_:
    new_list1.append(inner_list[0])
    new_list2.append(inner_list[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list= [[1633425661439, 0.11643042583898743], [1633428739018, 0.11682454707026001], [1633432086311, 0.11950356856187618]]
new_list1 = [ ] 
new_list2 = [ ] 
for inner_list in list:
   new_list1.append(inner_list[0])
   new_list2.append(inner_list[1])
print(new_list1)
print(new_list2)
```

Comment: Your solution will only add one element to new_list1 and new_list2 while more are expected. Without loops it would be also restricted to the exact number of elements from the sample.